# Find the orthogonal projection of b onto a

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Given  $${\mathbf a} = (-10, -8, 9) $$and $${\mathbf b} = (4, 5, 8) $$
Can someone please define what it means to find the orthogonal projection of b onto a?

Also what is the formula for computing the orthogonal projection of b onto a?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** 
Using the formula for b projection a I get the vectors:
$$(80/245, 64/245, -72/245)$$ 
But that's incorrect for the orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonal projection of a vector $b$ onto a vector $a$ is its component in the direction of $a$. The formula for this is:

$$\mathrm{proj \,\textbf{b}_{\textbf{a}}} = \frac{a \cdot b}{a \cdot a}a$$

This should intuitively make sense. Consider the definition of the dot product in geometric terms, and notice that the projection must be in the direction of $a$.

Now plug your vectors into this formula and get an answer.

Comment: But then how would that differ from the projection of b onto a?

Comment: In three dimensions, they're the same thing. One generally reserves the term projection for computations in three dimensions.